# Chrome/IE open link in current window?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

Hey guys, is there a way to open a link in the current tab if the link wants to open a new window? (In IE and Chrome).

Example, there is a link redirecting to google.com that opens up in a new window, i want to open that link in my current tab but if i right click my only options are:

- Open in new tab
- Open in new window
- Open

None of which will accomplish what i am asking.

The fastest way i currently know how to do this is right clicking on the link, selecting copy shortcut, pressing Alt + D (highlight address bar), pressing Ctrl + v then hitting enter

Comment: Are you looking for an "Open in current tab" option?  If so, the only way I know is to copy the link and paste in to the current tab.

Comment: @DLux, yes that is what i am looking for

Comment: You can drag the link up to the address bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably works in Chrome as well (haven't checked), but in IE just hold down the left mouse button down over the link and drag the link over to the tab you want it to open up in and release the mouse button. And there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the link, select , paste that into your address bar and press enter.

Someone could probably write a plugin that would add that to the context menu or enable a special key/click combination to do that if there were enough demand for it.